# sed script to read file1 and search and replace in file2

Tags: replace, sed

I have two different files:

**File1 contains:**

```
idd = home_mine
password = my_password
```

**File2 contains:**

```
// some generic information
otherfields = generic 
idd = generic_id 
psk = generic_password 
last_fields = generic_last
```

I would like to replace the 'iid' in file2 with **idd** contained in file1.

I would like to replace the 'psk' in file2 with **password** contained in file1. (I would like file1 password field to differ from psk).

**So that file2 will look like:**

```
//some generic info
otherfields = generic 
iid = home_mine 
psk = my_password 
last_fields = generic_last
```

Is there a sed script that can do this? 
Speed or efficiency are not a concern.

Thank you.

Comment: I think it's something like this but I have gotten it to work:

Comment: while read line;
do
  sed "/idd/s/$/$line/g \c" file2 
done < file1

Comment: where is your output going? I think you want `sed -i  '/idd/....' file2` , `sed -i"" /idd/.../.../' file2` on OSX, or if you're using an old unixen system, then `sed '/idd/.../.../' file2 > file2.out && mv file2.out file2`. Also I don't see how the `/g` can help in this case. Extend your comment as an answer with a solution where we can copy/paste your example and you can accept it for valuable reputation points. I'll upvote it too, for what that's worth. Good luck.

Comment: I have this sed script working but it is in a single file.  I would like to have a simple file1 that a non-technical person could easily edit:

Comment: /bin/sed -i '/ iid=/ c\  iid="home_mine"' ./file2,   
/bin/sed -i '/ psk=/ c\  password=my_passwork' ./file2

Answer (score 1):

I'd use awk:

```
awk -F '[[:blank:]]*=[[:blank:]]*' -v OFS=" = " '
    NR == FNR {my_val[$1] = $2; next} 
    $1 == "iid" {$2 = my_val["idd"]}       # is the key "idd" or "iid"?
    $1 == "psk" {$2 = my_val["password"]} 
    {print}
' file1 file2
```

The complicated `-F` value slurps up whitespace surrounding the `=` to form the input field separator. The output field separator uses a single space on each side.

Comment: Tank you. can you show where I would search in the file for "iid" and "psk"?   Thank you